# Undefined paperclip method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip, undefined

I am getting a method is undefined error in my Rails project. This method is used by the plugin paperclip. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is the beginning of my picture class:

require "paperclip"

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif','image/bmp']
  validates_attachment_presence :photo, :message => 'is required'

  belongs_to :incident
  belongs_to :user
...
```

Here's my error:

```
Extracted source (around line #122):

119: <%= link_to 'Printable', { :action => 'print', :id => @incident.id }, { :target => '_blank', :class => "button" } %>
120: <% if isviewable?(@incident) %>
121: 
122:   <%= link_to "Pictures (#{@incident.pictures.count})", incident_pictures_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>
123:   <%= link_to "Suspects (#{@incident.suspects.count})", incident_suspects_path(@incident), :class => "button" %>

Application trace:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1998:in `method_missing'
/Users/grantmc/Dev/railsprojects/Police/app/models/picture.rb:5
/Users/grantmc/Dev/railsprojects/Police/app/views/incidents/show.html.erb:122:in `_run_erb_app47views47incidents47show46html46erb'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `attr_accessible` in your model.

Paperclip have some attribute which is not part of your model, so you have to explicitly asign  `attr_accessor` to them like `attr_accessor :attach`

Comment: So in this case I would need `attr_accesor :photo` in my model?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that line of code yields the exact same error. The error message leads me to believe that for some reason the model cannot "see" the paperclip plugin because it doesn't recognize the validates_attachment_content_type method.